# Searching for specific tag values accross multiple files in directory with flat files

Tags: regex, code-snippets

We have a lot of SQL scripts stored in a shared directory (cca 500). It is organized in folders, however tree structure is not the best one since one file can be assigned to more categories (folders).

I thought I can tag all the files with some addition information, e.g. by adding one line to each file:

```
/* Project<ProjectName>, Department<DepartmentName> Tags<Tag1, Tag2, Tag3> */
```

and use some regex to search only in these tags. Is there a way how this can be achieved?

**How to find all files where Project=ProjectName and one of tags is Tag1?**

More detail: We would like to have easy-to-use, easily searchable shared repository of SQL scripts. We do not need versioning (sql scripts are mostly snippets of code). I've tried Git (way too complex for this task), Trac Wiki - too much additional work to store & load scripts (we use PostgreSQL and pgAdmin/Squirell). This is why I end up with plain shared directory - the only problem is that content is not easily searchable. I can search all the files at once (using e.g. SublimeText), but think this can be dramatically improved by finding answer to this question.

Comment: Where do you want to put that additional info? In the filename?

Comment: I would like to have in the file directly.

Comment: So you still need to search inside all files. And you can easily put more content inside your file, so what exactly are you asking here?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth My fault, I've added clarification.

Comment: What about file links so that you can have one real file and multiple links for multiple categories.